# Как отправить письмо на почту в php

Tags: php

Написал простейшую функцию функцию отправки без всяких проверок:

```
$message = "Проверка почты";
$to = "test@gmail.com";
$subject = "Тема сообщения";
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

Сервер XAMPP, как посмотреть куда оправилось письмо? Понимаю что не на настоящую почту, но нигде не могу найти

Вот мой [mail function]:

```
 ;For Win32 only. 
 ;php.net/smtp 
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com 
; php.net/smtp-port 
smtp_port=587 
; For Win32 only.
 ; php.net/sendmail-from ;
sendmail_from = yuaroslav29@gmail.com 
sendmail_path = "D:\Programm_for_study\XAMPP\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Вот [sendmail]

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com 
smtp_port=587 
auth_username=yuaroslav29@gmail.com 
auth_password=*пароль*
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос уже рассмотрен:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: Сделал точно так же, все равно нигде нет письма

Comment: _Понимаю что не на настоящую почту, но нигде не могу найти_ На какую укажите - на такую и отправится. `mail()` юзать не советую, она, по сути, не отправляет письма

Comment: Указал настоящую, но письма нигде нет все равно

Comment: Тогда как я могу отправить письмо?

Comment: Вам @Jug-IT выше ссылку кинул - вот так и отправляйте

Comment: Я сделал все в точности как там, результата нет

Comment: Покажите что и как делали

Comment: Указал в вопросе что изменил согласно той статье